# Which class used in elasticsearch 1.5.1 insted of package org.elasticsearch.common.mvel2

Tags: java, elasticsearch

can any one tel me there is a class or package using elastic search `1.5.1` instead of `org.elasticsearch.common.mvel2`. I have already using elastic search `1.3.1` version and now I install `1.5.1` elastic search. When I rebuild the project i got the following error:

> Error : "package org.elasticsearch.common.mvel2 does not exist"

Can any one suggest me the right package for elastic search 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvel` [has been deprecated and removed](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/6610) from Elasticsearch core. Instead, it's been made available as a plugin: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-mvel

So, for 1.5.1 (and 1.4.x actually) you should start using the `elasticsearch-lang-mvel` plugin.

Comment: Hi Andrei Stefan thanks for your response.I have already used some of  the classes in this mvel packages.so kindly tell me how can i used it in new version

Comment: I have no idea what you are using that package for in your project. `elasticsearch-lang-mvel` has a pom.xml file so I'm assuming is being made available in a Maven repo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-mvel/1.5.0. Include the jar in your project (via Maven or whatever building system you have), look in [the source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-lang-mvel) to see which classes and packages you need and give it a try.

Comment: Hi Andrei Stefan thanks for your help it will worked.but when i built the maven project i faced the "org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: " error.can u help me to fix it.i cant get the correct soultion for it .

Comment: :-) that's a different story and probably nothing to do with the original post.